# developing a windows application using win api

Tags: windows, api, winapi

Did every application of windows is developed using WINDOWS API?
Or they use any any other kind of languages.
Can any give me the good tutorial links for developing windows application's.

Comment: The winapi is not a language, it is a bunch functions.  That any language runtime support library knows how to use to make the program written in an arbitrary language work on Windows.

Answer (score 3):

Essentially, all applications running on Windows are built on top of the Windows API. This includes applications written in [.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/w0x726c2.aspx) and [WinRT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211377.aspx). Both of these systems are implemented in terms of the Windows API.

When it comes to developing applications there are countless options. You can develop Windows applications using the Windows API (C/C++/Delphi/...), the .NET framework (C#/Visual Basic.NET/F#/C++-CLI/...), or WinRT (with language projections for just about any language out there, like C++/CX).

On top of that there are numerous (GUI) frameworks available, like MFC, Qt, Windows Forms, or WPF.

Regardless of the platform, programming language, or framework, all applications will eventually call into the Windows API. Even if your next project is not going to target the Windows API directly, it's always a good idea to know what's going on underneath. A very good and compact introduction to Windows API programming is [theForger's Win32 API Tutorial](http://winprog.org/tutorial/). For the definitive guide you should check out Charles Petzold's [Programming Windows](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/157231995X).

Comment: If you really want to get into it more, and aren't afraid of C code, the book Programming Windows by Charles Petzold is a very good resource.

Comment: @Alex Added the link to the book. Since [Petzold is all XAML](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0735671761/) these days this avoids any confusion. And yes, although it was published 15 years ago it is still relevant.